# What is an open source Java project I could contribute to?

Tags: java, open-source

I'm looking for an open source project written in Java with a relatively low barrier to entry, ie. not hugely complex, friendly, etc.

My background is mostly in web apps so, that'd be the best place for me to start.  Mostly, I'm just looking for some place I can do some stuff in free time and keep my chops polished.

I plan on browsing through various public listings but thought I'd see if the Stack Overflow community had any suggestions.  Maybe someone even has a pet project...

Comment: What kind of open source are you looking for? Web app, Desktop app, any particular area at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the [Apache Foundation](http://www.apache.org/) projects are Java. Take a look at them and see what you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on field of intrest e.g. medical, engineering, communications, etc.

[SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net) classifies open source projects as such. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This mostly depends on your interesets and knowledge. After knowing this, you can browser perhaps Sourceforge, they should offer some additional search parameters like active contributors count, lines of code etc. This should show you some opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

Check out terracotta.org.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache POI HWPF [Apache POI HWPF](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) is even openly advertising the need for someone to take over this project. It is a Java API to handle Microsoft Word files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [github](https://github.com/search?l=Java&nwo=libgdx/libgdx&o=desc&p=6&q=Java&ref=cmdform&s=&search_target=global&type=Repositories) website and [Google-code](https://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3AJava&filter=0&mode=&start=0), you have couple of java projects which you can contribute to.